# How to show substeps in an algorithm environment

Tags: numbering, algorithm2e

I would like to automatically show substeps such as **1.1**. However, I can only do this manually.

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
    \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}

    Precomputation of multiplier \linebreak
        \textbf{1.1}  $g_0$ = 1 \linebreak
        \textbf{1.2} For $i$ from $1$ to ($2^k-1$) do: $g_i = g_{i-1}\cdot g$\\

    A = 1 \\
    For $i$ from $t$ down to $0$ do the following: \linebreak
        \textbf{3.1}  $A = A^{2^k}$ \linebreak
        \textbf{3.2} $A = A \cdot g_{d_i}$\\
    Return(A)
    \caption{Left-to-right k-ary exponentiation}
\end{algorithm}
```

Do can the numbering of these substeps automatically be added?

Comment: Please provide a MWE, not just fragments

Comment: @null Before asking a new question, it would be great if you could consider accepting the answers of your previous questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option that sets up a block called `\BEGIN` as part of a `substeps` environment<sup>*</sup>. The environment is constructed using [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ), for ease-of-use.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,nosemicolon,noline]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcounter{parentAlgoLine}
\SetKwBlock{BEGIN}{}{}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{substeps}{%
  \refstepcounter{AlgoLine}% <---- remove if necessary
  \protected@edef\theparentequation{\theequation}%
  \setcounter{parentAlgoLine}{\value{AlgoLine}}%
  \setcounter{AlgoLine}{0}%
  \def\theAlgoLine{\theparentAlgoLine.\arabic{AlgoLine}}%
  \BEGIN{\BODY}%
  \setcounter{AlgoLine}{\value{parentAlgoLine}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  Precomputation of multiplier
  \begin{substeps}
  $g_0 = 1$\;
  For $i$ from $1$ to ($2^k-1$) do: $g_i = g_{i-1} \cdot g$\;
  \end{substeps}

  $A = 1$\;
  For $i$ from $t$ down to $0$ do the following:
  \begin{substeps}
    $A = A^{2^k}$ \;
    $A = A \cdot g_{d_i}$ \;
  \end{substeps}
  Return($A$)\;
  \caption{Left-to-right $k$-ary exponentiation}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Note the use of `\;` for line-endings. This forms part of the [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) syntax.

I'd rather use something that's more native to `algorithm2e` with `\For` block constructions and no `substeps`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,nosemicolon,noline,noend]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  %Precomputation of multiplier\;
  $g_0 = 1$\;
  \For{\bfseries\upshape $i$ from $1$ to $(2^k-1)$}{
    $g_i = g_{i-1} \cdot g$
  }

  $A = 1$\;
  \For{\bfseries\upshape $i$ from $t$ down to $0$}{
    $A = A^{2^k}$ \;
    $A = A \cdot g_{d_i}$ \;
  }
  \Return{$A$}\;
  \caption{Left-to-right $k$-ary exponentiation}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The indentation should clarify the grouping/blocks.

<sub><sup>*</sup>
This environment was taken from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `subequations` environment.</sub>